# bugzilla installation on debian

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, bugzilla

I wanted to setup bugzilla on my debian vm.

Everything runs pretty smooth until i do the test suggested by the official manual:

```
./testserver.pl http://www.localhost/bugzilla
```

which returns:

```
TEST-FAILED Fetch of images/padlock.png failed
Your web server could not fetch http://www.localhost/bugzilla/images/padlock.png.
Check your web server configuration and try again.
```

the things i have done up until this point:

changed the localconfig of bugzilla:

```
$webservergroup = 'www-data';
$db_driver = 'mysql';
$db_pass = 'myDemoPass';
```

surfing to `http://localhost/bugzilla/` results into a site not found error.

the bugzilla folder is located at **/var/www/html/**

**What could be the reason?**

Specs:

Debian 7, Apache2, MySQL, Pearl

Edit: i did a new clean install of debian on a seperate vm and reached a point where i get this error message:

```
Syntax error on line 73 of apache2.conf
Apache2::SizeLimit at the moment works only with non-threaded MPMs...
```

the lines i added to apache2.conf:

```
PerlSwitches -w -T
PerlConfigRequire /var/www/html/bugzilla/mod_perl.pl
```

Comment: Aside from the obvious typo?

Comment: could you elaborate further? i took those 2 lines for the apache2.conf from the official install manual.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the issue of `Apache2::SizeLimit at the moment works only with non-threaded MPMs`: Bugzilla will only run with Apache's prefork multi-processing module [MPM]. If your Apache build is running another MPM, then Bugzilla will throw this error.

I was having the same issue and was finally able to get the default `index.cgi` page to load in my browser by changing the multi-processing module that Apache was using. I ran the command `a2dismod mpm_event` to un-symlink the event module from the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directory, then ran `a2enmod mpm_prefork` to symlink the prefork module [which was already in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`]. Finally, I restarted the server with `service apache2 restart` so Apache could start using the newly-symlinked module.

[list of mpm commands](http://simonholywell.com/post/2009/01/enabling-sites-and-modules-in-apache-on-ubuntu-or-debian.html) 
|
[Bugzilla note on using prefork](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/configuration.html#http-apache-mod_perl)
|
Older but relevant information on Apache2's symlinking help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html

Answer (score 1):

Another hint concerning the `SizeLimit` issue: On Debian, I simply did

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork
```

This automatically uninstalled `apache2-mpm-worker`. Read also the [package description](https://packages.debian.org/de/wheezy/apache2-mpm-prefork). Bugzilla now works well.